# Product of Countable Well-Ordered Set with $[0,1)$ is Homeomorphic to $[0,1)$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, order-theory, well-orders

As part of a proof that the long line is locally Euclidean, I'd like to prove the following:

**Proposition.** If $A$ is a countable well-ordered set, then $A \times [0,1)$ with the dictionary order is homeomorphic to $[0,1)$.

My proof is below. I'd like to know if this proof is correct and if there's a prettier proof out there.

*Proof*. For each $\alpha \in A$, pick $\epsilon_\alpha > 0$ so that $\sum_{\alpha \in A} \epsilon_\alpha = 1$. Define $f: A \times [0,1) \to [0,1)$ by
$$
  f(\alpha, t) = t\epsilon_\alpha + \sum_{\beta < \alpha}\epsilon_\beta.
$$
It's not hard to see that if $(\alpha_1,t_1) < (\alpha_2,t_2)$, then $f(\alpha_1,t_1) < f(\alpha_2,t_2)$. Thus $f$ is injective and if we can show it's surjective, it will automatically be a homeomorphism.

$X := f(A \times [0,1))$ is a disjoint union of intervals with lengths $\epsilon_\alpha$, so $X$ has Lebesgue measure $1$ and is therefore dense in $[0,1)$. Let $x \in [0,1)$ be arbitrary; we'll show that $x \in X$. If $x=0$ then we're done, since then $x = f(\alpha_0, 0)$ where $\alpha_0$ is the smallest element of $A$. So assume $x \in (0,1)$. For all $\alpha \in A$, let
$$
  x_\alpha := \sum_{\beta < \alpha} \epsilon_\beta = f(\alpha, 0).
$$
Since $X$ is dense, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find some $f(\alpha_n', t) \in (x-1/n,x]$. Let $\alpha_n$ be the successor of $\alpha_n'$. If $x \leq x_{\alpha_n'}$, then clearly $x \in [x_{\alpha_n'}, x_{\alpha_n}] \subseteq X$. Otherwise, $x_{\alpha_n} \in (x-1/n,x)$. We thus get a sequence $(x_{\alpha_n})$ which converges to $x$. Pick an increasing subsequence and rename it $(x_{\alpha_n})$; we still have $x_{\alpha_n} \to x$.

We'll show that $x_{\alpha_n} \to x_\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the smallest element of $A$ greater than all the $\alpha_n$. Since $[0,1)$ is Hausdorff, it will follow that $x = x_\alpha$, and we'll be done. Clearly $x \leq x_\alpha$ since all $x_{\alpha_n} < x_\alpha$. For the reverse direction, let $y < x_\alpha$ be arbitrary. Then by the definition of $x_\alpha$, there exists a finite collection $\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k\} \subseteq A$ with all $\beta_i < \alpha$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k \epsilon_{\beta_i} > y$. By the definition of $\alpha$ and the fact that $(\alpha_n)$ is increasing, there exists some $\alpha_n$ greater than all the $\beta_i$. It then follows that
$$
  y < \sum_i \epsilon_{\beta_i} \leq x_{\alpha_n} \leq x.
$$
Since $y$ was arbitrary, we have $x \geq x_\alpha$, and we conclude that $x = x_\alpha$.

Comment: I think that  to show $ (\alpha_1,t_1) < (\alpha_2,t_2) \implies f(\alpha_1,t_1) < f(\alpha_2,t_2),$ you will need $ \alpha_1 < \alpha_2 \implies \epsilon_{\alpha_1} < \epsilon_{\alpha_2}$, which can be done, but is not in your proof. That is, an additional constraint on $\{ \epsilon_{\alpha} :\alpha \in A\}$ is needed.

Comment: Theorem (Cantor). IF $(S,<)$ is an infinite linear order without endpoints,  and $S$ is separable & connected in the $<$-order topology, THEN $(S,<)$ is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb R.$ This is not difficult to prove and does not need the use of ordinals or well-orders (Find a dense subset of $S$ that is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$). From this, it is a short step to show $\{b:b<a\}\times [0,1)$ is order-isomorphic to $[0,\infty)$ whenever $\min A\ne a\in A$.

Comment: @Nick, I've found more issues with your proof that I managed to miss before, and have added discussion to my answer addressing them. In addition, I've included an explicit example which should help you get a better sense for many of the areas discussed.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, we don't require monotonicity of $\alpha\mapsto\epsilon_\alpha$ to show that $f$ is increasing, actually. If $0\leq t_1<t_2<1,$ then for any $\alpha\in A,$ $$f(\alpha,t_1)-t_1\epsilon_\alpha=\sum_{\beta<\alpha}\epsilon_\beta=f(\alpha,t_2)-t_2\epsilon_\alpha,$$ and so $$0<(t_2-t_1)\epsilon_\alpha=f(\alpha,t_2)-f(\alpha,t_1).$$ On the other hand, if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in A$ such that $\alpha_1<\alpha_2,$ then letting $\gamma$ be the immediate successor of $\alpha_1,$ we easily see for any $t_1,t_2\in[0,1)$ that $$f(\alpha_1,t_1)<f(\gamma,0)≤f(\alpha_2,0)≤f(\alpha_2,t_2).$$

Comment: (continued) Moreover, $\alpha\mapsto\epsilon_\alpha$ cannot be monotone nondecreasing if $A$ is infinite, or $f(\alpha,t)$ will fail to be defined for $\alpha$ corresponding to infinite ordinals, due to series divergence. Likewise, $\alpha\mapsto\epsilon_\alpha$ cannot be monotone nonincreasing if $A$ has order type greater than $\omega$--indeed, if $\beta$ is the element of $A$ corresponding to $\omega,$ then there can be at most finitely-many $\alpha\in A$ with $\alpha<\beta$ such that $\epsilon_\alpha≥\epsilon_\beta,$ or else we run into the same problem with $f.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof: without loss of generality, take $A$ to be an [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). We proceed by [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Transfinite_induction). Note we need to add the hypothesis that $A$ is nonempty.

When we have a totally ordered set $I$ and, for each $i \in I$, a totally ordered set $S_i$, we can form the “sum order” $\sum\limits_{i \in I} S_i$, whose underlying set is $\coprod\limits_{i \in I} S_i$ and which is ordered first by $i$, then by the order of $S_i$. In the case where $I$ is well-ordered and each $S_i$ is well-ordered, this gives a well-ordered set, which is identified with its order type. As a special case, $S_1 + S_2 := \sum\limits_{i \in \{1, 2\}} S_i$. Note that sums left-distribute over products.

Base case: $A = 1$. Trivial.

Inductive step 1: $A = B + 1$. In this case, we see that $(B + 1) \times [0, 1) \cong B \times [0, 1) + 1 \times [0, 1) \cong [0, 1) + [0, 1) \cong [0, 1) + [1, 2) \cong [0, 2) \cong [0, 1).$

Inductive step 2: $A$ is a limit ordinal. Then $A$ has [cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Cofinality) $\omega$, which means we can write $A = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty B_i$ where $B_i < A$ for all $i$. Then we have $A \times [0, 1) = (\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_i) \times [0, 1) \cong \sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (B_i \times [0, 1)) \cong \sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} [0, 1) \cong \sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} [i, i + 1) \cong [0, \infty) \cong [0, 1).$

Comment: I've never actually learned about ordinals or transfinite induction, but is my proof essentially the same strategy as this one, but more cumbersome?

Comment: @NickA. Your strategy is a bit more direct, and attempts to provide a way to construct an order isomorphism without need to consider which (or which kind of) countable well-order type is involved. Mark's approach is far simpler, **if** you're familiar with ordinals and transfinite induction. See my answer for critique of your proof approach.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Saving demonstrates in his answer, an approach by transfinite induction is probably the simplest, if you're familiar with the concept.

As an alternative, a theorem due to Cantor is that if $\langle S,\prec\rangle$ is a countably infinite strict total order with no $\prec$-least or $\prec$-greatest element, and if $\prec$ is a *dense* relation on $S$--meaning that for any $x,y\in S$ with $x\prec y,$ there exists $z\in S$ such that $x\prec z\prec y$--then $\langle S,\prec\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\langle\Bbb Q,<\rangle.$ Used in conjunction with the other result of Cantor's [mentioned above by Daniel Wainfleet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623130/product-of-countable-well-ordered-set-with-0-1-is-homeomorphic-to-0-1#comment9838137_4623130), along with some basic cardinality results involving countably infinite (enumerated) sets, the result you're trying to prove follows readily.

Now on to your proof.

---

Your strategy is solid, but there are a few issues.

The first issue is actually with the statement, itself, as "countable" typically means "finite or countably infinite," so includes the possibility that $A$ is the empty set, in which case the claim is false. It is probably simpler to deal with the non-empty finite case separately by defining order isomorphisms $A\times[0,1)\mapsto[0,n)\mapsto[0,1)$ for the appropriate $n,$ but the following could instead be adjusted to accommodate the finite cases, too, by specifying a different (finite) sequence $\langle\epsilon_\alpha\rangle_{\alpha\in A}.$

> For each $\alpha \in A$, pick $\epsilon_\alpha > 0$ so that $\sum_{\alpha \in A} \epsilon_\alpha = 1$.

It isn't difficult to see what you're going for here, but one could even be explicit. I might say something like "Since $A$ is countably infinite, then there is a bijection $g$ from $A$ to the set of positive integers. For each $\alpha\in A,$ let $\epsilon_\alpha:=2^{-g(\alpha)}.$ By unconditional convergence, we have $$\sum_{\alpha\in A}\epsilon_\alpha=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}=1."$$

Even this, though, may be on shaky ground, as (un)conditional convergence results are often proved about sequences of finite partial sums, specifically, rather than the more general sort of series that you're wanting to use to define the function $f,$ so it may need to be justified even more carefully (*e.g.*: by transfinite induction) unless you have a stronger result to refer to.

> Define $f: A \times [0,1) \to [0,1)$ by
> $$
>   f(\alpha, t) = t\epsilon_\alpha + \sum_{\beta < \alpha}\epsilon_\beta.
> $$

It is not hard to justify that $[0,1)$ is a codomain for the function $f$ thus defined, and should be done.

> It's not hard to see that if $(\alpha_1,t_1) < (\alpha_2,t_2)$, then $f(\alpha_1,t_1) < f(\alpha_2,t_2)$.

True, nor is it hard to show it, which a proof should.

> Thus $f$ is injective and if we can show it's surjective, it will automatically be a homeomorphism.

This is true. However, the important thing isn't injectivity, but rather the fact that it's *strictly increasing*. Otherwise, we could (for example) show that the set of positive integers is order isomorphic to the set of negative integers (both under the usual order relation), which is false.

> $X := f(A \times [0,1))$ is a disjoint union of intervals with lengths $\epsilon_\alpha$, so $X$ has Lebesgue measure $1$ and is therefore dense in $[0,1)$.

This is true, but should be shown. Using the notation $x_\alpha$ as you define later, one can show that for each $\alpha\in A,$ the image of $\{\alpha\}\times[0,1)$ under $f$ is $[x_\alpha,x_\alpha+\epsilon_\alpha),$ which shows the length of the component intervals. The fact that $f$ is strictly increasing provides the justification that these intervals are pairwise disjoint. Moreover, we need the fact that $A$ is ***countable*** to conclude that the union's Lebesgue measure is the sum of the individual measures--otherwise, it would follow from a similar argument that the Lebesgue measure of the real line is $0$ (as a disjoint union of singletons), which is clearly ridiculous.

> Let $x \in [0,1)$ be arbitrary; we'll show that $x \in X$. If $x=0$ then we're done, since then $x = f(\alpha_0, 0)$ where $\alpha_0$ is the smallest element of $A$. So assume $x \in (0,1)$. For all $\alpha \in A$, let
> $$
>   x_\alpha := \sum_{\beta < \alpha} \epsilon_\beta = f(\alpha, 0).
> $$
> Since $X$ is dense, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find some $f(\alpha_n', t) \in (x-1/n,x]$.

This is true, but we can be explicit. I would say "If $x=x_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in A,$ then $x=f(\alpha,0)\in X,$ and we're done. Suppose instead that for all $\alpha\in A,$ $x\neq x_\alpha.$" This assumption comes in handy soon.

"Since $X$ is dense in $[0,1)$ and $A$ is well-ordered, then for each positive integer $n,$ the set $$A_n:=\left\{\alpha\in A\mid\exists t\in[0,1): x-\frac{1}{n}<f(\alpha,t)\leq x\right\}$$ is non-empty."

"Note that if for some positive integer $n,$ the set $A_n$ were to have a greatest element, say $\beta,$ then $\beta$ would be the greatest element of $A_n$ for **all** positive integers $n.$" (Do you see why?) "Then we must have $x_\beta\leq f(\beta,t)\leq x$ for some $t\in[0,1),$ so $x_\beta\leq x,$ and so $x_\beta<x$ by our earlier assumption. Moreover, if $\gamma\in A$ such that $x_\gamma<x,$ then taking $n$ sufficiently large so that $x_\gamma<x-\frac{1}{n}<x,$ we then have that $$f(\gamma,0)=x_\gamma<f(\beta,t)$$ for some $t\in[0,1),$ so $(\gamma,0)<(\beta,t),$ and so $\gamma\leq\beta.$ Since for all $\gamma\in A$ we have $x_\gamma<x\implies\gamma\leq\beta,$ then by contrapositive, if $\gamma\in A$ such that $\beta<\gamma,$ we have $x\leq x_\gamma,$ and so $x<x_\gamma$ by our earlier assumption."

"In particular, if $\beta$ is **not** the maximum element of $A,$ then letting $\gamma$ be its immediate successor, we have $$x\in[x_\beta,x_\gamma)=[x_\beta,x_\beta+\epsilon_\beta)=f\bigl(\{\beta\}\times[0,1)\bigr)\subseteq X,$$ and we're done. On the other hand, if $\beta$ **is** the maximum element of $A,$ then $$x_\beta+\epsilon_\beta=\sum_{\alpha\in A}\epsilon_\alpha=1,$$ so letting $t=\frac{x-x_\beta}{\epsilon_\beta},$ we have that $t>0$ as a quotient of positive numbers, but also that $$t<\frac{1-x_\beta}{\epsilon_\beta}=1,$$ and that $$x=x_\beta+t\epsilon_\beta=f(\beta,t)\in X.$$ Thus, if the sets $A_n$ have a (common) greatest element, then $x\in X,$ as desired."

"Finally, suppose that the sets $A_n$ have no greatest elements, so are each infinite. Note that $A_1$ has the minimum of $A$ as an element--denote it by $\alpha_1'.$ For all positive integers $n,$ let $\alpha_{n+1}'$ denote the least element of $A_{n+1}$ which is greater than $\alpha_n'.$" (Do you see why such an element must exist?) Doing it this way lets us ensure that each $\alpha_n'$ **HAS** a successor, and that the sequence of these successors is strictly increasing.

> Let $\alpha_n$ be the successor of $\alpha_n'$. If $x \leq x_{\alpha_n'}$, then clearly $x \in [x_{\alpha_n'}, x_{\alpha_n}] \subseteq X$.

You've got a typo here, where you say "$x\leq x_{\alpha_n'},$" instead of what you probably meant. Aside from fixing the typo, another thing I would change here is to say "If $x\leq x_{\alpha_n}$ *for some positive integer* $n,$ then clearly $x\in[x_{\alpha_n'},x_{\alpha_n}].$" At that point, I would also recommend that you justify the inclusion $[x_{\alpha_n'},x_{\alpha_n}]\subseteq X,$ which is straightforward.

> Otherwise, $x_{\alpha_n} \in (x-1/n,x)$.

Here, I'd add the important phrase "...for all positive integers $n.$"

> We thus get a sequence $(x_{\alpha_n})$ which converges to $x$. Pick an increasing subsequence and rename it $(x_{\alpha_n})$; we still have $x_{\alpha_n} \to x$.

This need to redefine your notation could be avoided by defining the sequence $\langle\alpha_n'\rangle_{n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}}$ more carefully from the start, as I outlined above.

> We'll show that $x_{\alpha_n} \to x_\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the smallest element of $A$ greater than all the $\alpha_n$.

Based only on what you've showed so far, there need be no such $\alpha,$ since it could be (for example) that all but finitely-many $\alpha_n'$ are equal to the greatest element of $A,$ in which case not even the sequence $\langle\alpha_n\rangle_{n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}}$ is defined!

Even if $A$ has no greatest element, though, it has to be justified that such an $\alpha$ must exist. Fortunately, if $A$ has no greatest element, one can prove that $\epsilon_\alpha$ must be less than $1-x$ for all sufficiently large $\alpha,$ whence one *can* show the existence of an $\alpha$ greater than all the $\alpha_n.$

> Since $[0,1)$ is Hausdorff, it will follow that $x = x_\alpha$, and we'll be done. Clearly $x \leq x_\alpha$ since all $x_{\alpha_n} < x_\alpha$.

Here, I'd say instead "since $x_{\alpha_n}\to x$ and all $x_{\alpha_n} < x_\alpha$."

> For the reverse direction, let $y < x_\alpha$ be arbitrary. Then by the definition of $x_\alpha$, there exists a finite collection $\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k\} \subseteq A$ with all $\beta_i < \alpha$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k \epsilon_{\beta_i} > y$.

The definition of $x_\alpha$ has nothing in particular to do with the fact that there is such a finite subset of $A.$ In point of fact, for **any** $y<1,$ there is a finite subset $B$ of $A$ such that $\sum_{\beta\in B}\epsilon_\beta>y.$ (Do you see why this is true?) Moreover, given such a set $B,$ there is no guarantee that there is any $n$ such that $\sum_{\beta\in B}\epsilon_\beta< x_{\alpha_n}.$

---

**Example**: It might be illustrative to consider the following. Let $A=\{1,2,3\}\times\Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$ in the dictionary order, so that $A$ is countable, non-empty, and well-ordered, with no maximum element. The elements of $A$ are ordered pairs $\langle k,m\rangle,$ and for each such pair, we let $\epsilon_{\langle k,m\rangle}=2^{-(k+3m)}.$ Define $f$ as you did above, and let $x=\frac67.$ It turns out that for any positive integer $n,$ the set $A_n$ (as I defined above) has no greatest element, which allows us to define the sequences $\langle\alpha_n'\rangle_{n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}}$ and $\langle\alpha_n\rangle_{n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}}$ as I did above.

Now, obviously, $\alpha_n=\langle k_n,m_n\rangle$ for each $n,$ but there are some other pertinent facts about the pair of sequences of integers $\langle k_n\rangle_{n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}}$ and $\langle m_n\rangle_{n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}}$ worth mentioning:

- $n\mapsto k_n$ is monotone nondecreasing, initially equal to $1,$ but eventually equal to $2.$
- $n\mapsto m_n$ is unbounded above, and eventually monotone nondecreasing.

It turns out that $\alpha=\langle 3,0\rangle$ is the least element of $A$ greater than all $\alpha_n,$ and that $x_\alpha=x.$ If we take an arbitrary $y<\frac67,$ then the set $B=\bigl\{\langle1,0\rangle, \langle2,0\rangle, \langle3,0\rangle\bigr\}$ has the property that $$y<\sum_{\beta\in B}\epsilon_\beta,$$ but we also have $x_{\alpha_n}<\sum_{\beta\in B}\epsilon_\beta$ for all $n.$ On the other hand, if we take $B$ to be an arbitrary finite subset consisting of *consecutive* elements of $A,$ then we have $\sum_{\beta\in B}\epsilon_\beta<\frac47.$

Fortunately, it turns out that we don't even *need* such a set $B.$

---

Instead of the approach you attempted to take with the set $B,$ one can prove by the density of $X$ in $[0,1)$ that if $y<x_\gamma=f(\gamma,0)$ for some $\gamma\in A,$ then there is some $\langle \beta,t\rangle\in A\times[0,1)$ such that $y<f(\beta,t)<f(\gamma,0).$ (I leave the details of this proof to you. It isn't too complicated.) Since $f$ is increasing, then we necessarily have $\beta<\gamma.$

In particular, for $\gamma=\alpha:=\sup_{n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}}\alpha_n,$ since $\beta<\gamma,$ then $\beta$ is not an upper bound of the sequence $\langle\alpha_n\rangle_{n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}}.$ Thus, there is some $n$ such that $\beta<\alpha_n,$ whence $\langle\beta,t\rangle < \langle\alpha_n,0\rangle,$ and so $$y<f(\beta,t)<f(\alpha_n,0)=x_{\alpha_n}<x.$$ Therefore, for all $y<x_\alpha,$ we have that $y<x,$ so we can't have $x<x_\alpha,$ but we have already seen that $x\leq x_\alpha,$ and so $x=x_\alpha,$ as desired, completing the proof.

I strongly encourage you to get your hands dirty with the example I constructed above to get a better feel for the problem. Taking $A'$ to be any specific infinite subset of $A$ with a greatest element and considering $A'\times[0,1)$ will shed yet more light.

Let me know if you have any questions about any of the points I discussed!